# Sqoop Increment with string column

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm trying to use an incremental sqoop job across all tables in a database. Some of the databases only have string values in the columns. Is there a way to increment on a string value? There is a common string name across all tables.

Comment: To my knowledge, you either have to have a numeric column or a date column to use incremental imports.  I have not seen it done with a string column.  Up-voting this question!

Comment: After some more thought, are the string values in the text column you refer to in some sort of increasing alpha-numeric order (eg., new rows always have a larger alpha-numeric order)?  Can you provide an example of the contents in the strings?

Comment: I was hoping to use an id string because it was the only column consistent across all tables but it doesn't seem to be increasing in any fashion I can recognize. There is a createdata in many of the tables but on the original import it was saved as type string not date. I'm not the one who did the original import so I'm running an import now to see if maybe they just didn't do it right.

Comment: Excellent -- if you have a date field you can actually use, you can just use 'lastmodified' mode instead of 'append' mode.  After my initial comment I was thinking if the question you asked even made sense.  It would if your database forced you to store either the record date or the incrementing number into a text column, but the odds of that is very slim.  Let us know if you get it working!

Comment: Got it working! It looks like the moral of the store is to not trust the hue web ui. It was listing the datatype as string and the variable name didn't have the correct casing on letters. I ran a sqoop query on the table and got the correct casing and it worked when I used lastmodified like you said. I'm fairly new to stackoverflow but if you let me know how to give you credit for helping I'll do it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my initial comment I was thinking if the question you asked even made sense. It would if your database forced you to store either the record date or the incrementing number into a text column, but the odds of that is very slim.

If you have a date field you can actually use, you can just use 'lastmodified' mode instead of 'append' mode.